# Deindent array, `\noindent` does not work

Tags: tables

How do I deindent the array below? `\noindent` does not work.

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{llc@{\quad\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
       \text{Item 1:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/}} \\
       \text{Item 2:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/}} \\
       \text{Item 3:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/}} \\ 
       \text{Item 4:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/}} \\
       \text{Item 5:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       \text{Item 6:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/}} \\
       \text{Item 7:} & \quad \text{\url{https://www.google.com/}} \\
   \end{array}
   \end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend
```

Comment: An equation is usually centred. Why are you actually using math mode to type normal text instead of `{tabular}`?

Comment: `\ignorespacesafterend` does nothing in that position.  I suspect you want to remove `equation*` and all the `\text{...]` and use `tabular` rather than `array` as there is no math here.

Comment: Also `\extracolsep{\fill}` does nothing. If your table has two columns, why are you allocating six?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please (a) get rid of all `\text` wrappers, (b) get rid of the `\quad` directives, (c) get rid of `\ignorespacesafterend`, (d) omit the `equation*` wrapper, (e) replace the `array` environment with a `tabular` environment, (f) replace `{llc@{\quad\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}` with `{@{}ll}`, and (g) insert a single `\noindent` directive before `\begin{tabular}`. Oh, and be sure to load the `xurl` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl} % https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
       Item 1 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       Item 2 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       Item 3 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       Item 4 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       Item 5 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       Item 6 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
       Item 7 & \url{https://www.google.com/} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **Mico**, thanks. How do you add space between rows to this?

Comment: @AlixBlaine - You could change `@{}ll` to, say, `@{}l@{\hspace{1in}}l`.